# How to add short vertical segment corresponding to observations on the x-axis?

Tags: r

ideal plot

[image: ideal plot]

my plot

[image: my plot]

Look at the difference between these two plots. Given dataset [Z], how could I show this dataset as "stitch" segment on the x-axis?

Great thanks!

Comment: More information is needed to get a meaningful answer. Poorly formed questions tend to get voted off the island. What do you mean by "dataset [Z]"? What do you mean by "stitch" segment? Answers that guess at your question are provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what is being asked is, "How does one add tick marks corresponding to observations on the X-axis?," the answer is to use the function `rug()` in base graphics. If you mean, "How does one add a legend (in the upper right corner)?," the function is `legend()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess stitch(), bush(), fuzz(). But actually it's rug()!!

Comment: You're welcome! I have  similar problems all the time. I turn to `apropos()` and `help.search()` (or `??<function>`) for this. Unfortunately  `help.search("stitch")` wouldn't have helped in this particular case. That's where Stackoverflow and Google can be really helpful!

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question in order to make it more clear for others. If this is edit is accepted, please accept the answer to help others who may have the same question.